# Logging erros in SQLite database from C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, sqlite, error-logging

I'm developing a win app in C# which communicates to a WCF Service. I want to log exceptions that are thrown on client to be logged in Sql Lite Database (Win app is using Sql Lite database for storing data locally). And then later it should be sent to the wcf service when required so that it can be useful for support/analysis/application improvement.

I want a method which can be directly called in every catch block simply by `LogHelper.Log(ex)`.

I would like to know if anyone has done it through Enterprise library or used any good practice for such situation?

**Update**
I'm already using sql lite database for storing data locally through System.Data.SqLite library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a number of blog posts on this recently. I'm sure one or the other will provide the answer that you need:

- [Lightweight, Aspect-Oriented Instrumentation with PostSharp, NLog, and SQLite](http://www.beckshome.com/index.php/2010/04/lightweight-aspect-oriented-instrumentation-with-postsharp-nlog-and-sqlite/)
- [Logging to SQLite with NLog](http://www.beckshome.com/index.php/2010/03/logging-to-sqlite-with-nlog/)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you were looking at EL. My posts address this challenge specifically with NLog. I too use EL when clients require it - never done it with SQLite. If you have a choice, I'd recommend you give NLog a look.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm looking into it. Seems that I can use it.

Comment: It would have been great if you can post the source code on your blog. Source code is always helpful.

[Jokingly] Do you know that developers read and understand code faster than English? :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use microsoft enterprise library with sqlite database as backend. Use [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) library for all database operations.

If you still want to use enterprise library check this [article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/ba7ea7a0-4e67-4863-941c-f4dadf9b7127/aspnet-using-sqlite-wit.aspx). Anyways you will have to install the System.Data.SQLite library. As per my experience [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) will be enough for all database operations.

One more word of caution, sqlite does not support concurrency. So any database operation will lock the entire datase for the duration.

Comment: I'm already using sql lite database for storing data locally through System.Data.SqLite library.

Answer (score -1):

add reference to your project System.data.sqlite
than call namespace for sqlite db connection
after than write basic logging coding. 
Apply it will definately work